# Quest PowerShell: Export AD permissions and apply them at a later stage

Tags: permissions, powershell, export, delegation

I'm trying to standardise our AD permissions for our 4 support groups. I've already applied permissions for 2 standard groups (Global support) and I'm now facing a painful clean-up for site based support for which there's a specific group to assign permissions to.
Obviously, if I can find an answer to this, I can look at implementing the permissions to the global groups as well for new OUs.
By permissions I mean delegation.

To speed up things, I already have certain OUs already set correctly, so what I've been doing is copying permissions and apply them to another OU. 
This is the structure of AD:
-Site 1
--Desktops
--Laptops
--Users
-Site 2
--Desktops
--Users

And so on.
Now, let's say I have Site 1 correctly configured (please note that I'm assigning permissions at each sub-OU, so Desktops, Laptops and so on). I would do the following for each group:

```
Get-QADPermission "OU=Users,OU=Site1,DC=contoso,DC=com" -Account "CONTOSO\_HelpDesk" | Add-QADPermission "OU=Users,OU=Site2,DC=contoso,DC=com"
```

Now, coming to the question:
How can I export those permissions for _HelpDesk in a file and re-import them in a later stage **on a different group**?
For instance, I want to export the permissions for _HelpDesk, save them to a file called _HelpDesk_delegation.txt (or whatever extension) and then, a week later, I want to import them in a variable and apply them to another OU for another Group, for instance OU=Users,OU=Site5,DC=contoso,DC=com and for _Site5-Local-IT group?

A bit hard to explain but the concept is there.

Bear in mind that right now I'm not able to even "live"copy the permissions for HelpDesk and assign them to _Site5-Local-IT with the above command.
Hopefully you can guide me through this little issue. One thing I've noticed is that Quest is way better in copy/apply permissions than the built-in AD module.

Thanks

Comment: Have you researched `Get-Acl` and `Set-Acl`?

Comment: I did. Problem is, they are also too complicated. I think there should be an easier way to just export all of the variable to a file, all of its content. It doesn't!

Answer (score -1):

There are scripts here to export and import:
https://www.akaplan.com/blog/2017/08/export-and-import-delegated-ou-permissions-with-powershell/

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.